# Compute $Tor_i^{\mathbb Z/ 6 \mathbb Z}(\mathbb Z/ 2\mathbb Z, \mathbb Z/ 2\mathbb Z)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, derived-functors

I am working on this problem, and here is what I figured out:

$\mathbb Z/ 6\mathbb Z \xrightarrow{\times 2} \mathbb Z/ 6\mathbb Z \xrightarrow{\times 3} \mathbb Z/ 6\mathbb Z \xrightarrow{\times2 } \mathbb Z/ 6\mathbb Z \rightarrow 0$ is a projective resolution of $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$.

Then tensor it with $\mathbb Z/ 2 \mathbb  Z$, we get the following sequence:

$\mathbb Z/ 2\mathbb Z \xrightarrow{0} \mathbb Z/ 2\mathbb Z \xrightarrow{id} \mathbb Z/ 2\mathbb Z \xrightarrow{0} \mathbb Z/ 2\mathbb Z \rightarrow 0$

So the left nth left derived functor would be zero if $n \neq 0$.

But there is a hint saying that we should use the formula $\mathbb Z/m \mathbb  Z \otimes \mathbb Z / n \mathbb Z = \mathbb Z / gcd(m,n) \mathbb Z$ to get a closed formula which confuses me since I did not use it at all.

Comment: I'd do it your way...

Comment: $R=\Bbb Z/6\Bbb Z$ is a semisimple ring. So all exact sequences of $R$-modules split, and so all derived functors on the category of $R$-modules are zero.